# Tensorflow. Kernel died when training. Window Anaconda

Tags: python, debugging, tensorflow, anaconda

```
   # Import data

    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
    import tensorflow as tf

    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data', one_hot=True)

    # Create the model

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
    k = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
    y = tf.nn.softmax(k)
    i = 0

    # Define loss and optimizer

    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
    learning_rate = 0.5
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(k, y_))
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    print ("Training")
    sess = tf.Session()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer() #.run()
    sess.run(init)
    for _ in range(1000):

        print(i)
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        print(i)
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
        print(i)
        i=i+1


    print ('b is ',sess.run(b))
    print('W is',sess.run(W))
```

## Explain.

This is MNIST code using softmax.
The problem appears at

sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

in the for loop.

Just kernel died and restarting with any error message.
Maybe the code is not the problem because it works well on other guy.

I'm using Windows10 Anaconda.

What is the problem?

Comment: From your mention of a "kernel" dying, it sounds like you are using Jupyter/IPython. You might get more information, including a better error message, if you run your script directly using `python.exe`. Can you try doing that and posting the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar problem as yours. It is likely that you installed `cuda` and `cudnn` and are running codes on `tensorflow-gpu`.

In my case, I at first installed `cuda8.0` and `cudnn v6.0 for cuda8.0`, and got the kernel died problem.

Then I changed the `cudnn` version to `cudnn v5.1 for cuda8.0` and solved this problem. Now I am working fine with my environment.